# expo-assets useAssets: Type 'Asset' is not assignable to type 'ImageSourcePropType'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo

Following the small example provided by [expo-asset's docs](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/asset/#useassets), passing an element from the asset array to an Image `source` prop gives the following typescript error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: ImageProps | Readonly<ImageProps>): Image', gave the following error.
    Type 'Asset' is not assignable to type 'ImageSourcePropType'.
      Type 'Asset' is not assignable to type 'ImageURISource'.
        Types of property 'width' are incompatible.
          Type 'number | null' is not assignable to type 'number | undefined'.
            Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'number | undefined'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: ImageProps, context: any): Image', gave the following error.
    Type 'Asset' is not assignable to type 'ImageSourcePropType'.ts(2769)
index.d.ts(3783, 5): The expected type comes from property 'source' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Image> & Readonly<ImageProps>'
index.d.ts(3783, 5): The expected type comes from property 'source' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Image> & Readonly<ImageProps>'
```

I'm on macOS using Node version 16.15.0, Yarn version 1.22.18 and expo-cli version 5.4.7.

The issue is reproducible by:

- initializing a new project with `expo init` and choosing the `blank (Typescript)` template
- adding expo-asset with `expo install expo-asset`

The `package.json` looks something like this (scripts removed for easier reading):

```json
{
  "name": "asset-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~45.0.0",
    "expo-asset": "~8.5.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@types/react": "~17.0.21",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.66.13",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

and with the following `App.tsx`:

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { Image, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { useAssets } from "expo-asset";

export default function App() {
  let [assets] = useAssets([require("./assets/icon.png")]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {assets ? <Image source={assets[0]} /> : null}
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

the mentioned error gets shown at line (10, 24) (on the `source` prop)

I really hope that I have done something wrong because it just seems to me that somehow the type definitions are incompatible (as in the `Asset` class' `width` property should be defined with `undefined` instead of `null`), so how do I fix this?

Comment: Hey, I'm having the same typing problem :/ I created an issue in the expo repo to see if we get any answers.

https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/18328

Answer (score 3):

The right form is using an object with `uri` key.
Like this:

```
export default function App() {
  let [assets] = useAssets([require("./assets/icon.png")]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {assets ? <Image source={{ uri: assets[0].uri }} /> : null}
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me - the image disappeared. Using the way described in the OP works, but gives a TS error.